# How to stop EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator from renaming columns?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t4

Using EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator v2.26.0 and I cannot find where to change the .tt to stop the column rename when generating the POCOs.  I suspect it is in UpdateColumn, which I've updated to just the single line:

```
UpdateColumn = (Column column, Table table) => column;
```

But still the columns get renamed from e.g. "Batch_ID" to "BatchId".

Without stopping the column rename, I'm getting the error:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'DocumentExport.DataAccess.Databases.Batches.Batch'. A member of the type, 'BatchId', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

How does one stop column renaming during POCO generation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the database.tt,

```
UsePascalCase = false;    // This will rename the generated C# tables & properties to use PascalCase. If false table & property names will be left alone.
```

While this accomplished suppressing column names, it also affected table names and possibly other things.